# DCOM Error 10010 The server {7D1933CB-86F6-4A98-8628-01BE94C9A575} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dcom

We've been experiencing this DCOM error message for the last month or two.  It doesn't appear to be doing any harm, but it's worrying that it's happening so frequently.

What steps do I need to take to diagnose the cause and how can I correct this issue?

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM
Date:          01/10/2013 14:04:46
Event ID:      10010
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      server.ourdomain.co.uk
Description:
The server {7D1933CB-86F6-4A98-8628-01BE94C9A575} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM" Guid="{1B562E86-B7AA-4131-BADC-B6F3A001407E}" EventSourceName="DCOM" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">10010</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-01T13:04:46.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>104649</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>server.ourdomain.co.uk</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">{7D1933CB-86F6-4A98-8628-01BE94C9A575}</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: {7D1933CB-86F6-4A98-8628-01BE94C9A575} is the "Virtual Disk Service" according to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7D1933CB-86F6-4A98-8628-01BE94C9A575}.  This service is set to Manual start and is currently "stopped" on the server.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue.  I can see "Virtual Disk Service" service starting, followed by the "The server {7D1933CB-86F6-4A98-8628-01BE94C9A575} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout." message, then the "Virtual Disk Service" stops 7 seconds later.  Same pattern every time.  Oddly, this service starts and stops all day long, but only ever ONCE a day does the DCOM error occur.  The error occurs around 24:38:57 apart.  You can pretty much guess +/- 30 seconds the next time the problem is going to occur.